# iOS RestKit response descriptor

Tags: ios, restkit

I want to create universal response descriptor with RestKit to catch errors from all REST responses. I'm using the following code:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *customErrorDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                keyPath:@"error_message"
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:customErrorDescriptor];
```

This only works for responses, where there is another response descriptor (usually for GET methods, where response is processed):

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorGet =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:@"/api/user/user"
                                                keyPath:@"data"
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

But it does not work for request without custom descriptor. For example:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor =
    [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[userMapping inverseMapping]
                                          objectClass:[User class]
                                          rootKeyPath:nil
                                               method:RKRequestMethodPUT];
```

It does not map the response with error:

> Expected an object mapping for class of type 'User', provider returned
>   one for 'RKErrorMessage'

However, when I add another response descriptor which match this request and error_message is present in the response, the universal error descriptor will successfully match the error:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorPut =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodPUT
                                            pathPattern:@"/api/user/updateCustomerProfile"
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

The problem with adding this descriptor is that when an error occurs it sometimes (about 50%) "catch" the response instead of the error descriptor (because both descriptors meet requirements).

I tried adding bogus keyPath to this descriptor. It works when error in response occurred, but it does give me warnings when response is OK:

> No mappable object representations were found at the key paths
>   searched., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable
>   to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched:
>   data, error_message The representation inputted to the mapper was
>   found to contain nested object representations at the following key
>   paths: result This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the
>   key paths for your mappings.

Comment: Presumably you do want to handle the success case? Show the code you're using to test the mapping result

Comment: I don't want to handle success case in post/put methods. In success post/put results there is no result anyway. I just need to handle errors. I'm not testing the mapping result. This is all the RestKit related code I'm using.